# Cannot drag and drop crystal report viewer onto web form in visual studio 2010 !

Tags: crystal-reports

I've installed crystal report in visual studio 2010. I can design reports. But when I created a web page and tried to drag and drop the Crystal Report Viewer, nothing happened! No viewer was added, no warning either. Please let me know how to fix this??? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with adding CrystalReportViewer to a Winform so I wrote a post on it in my Blog.  See if this helps you.

http://paul-j-power.blogspot.com/2011/01/oh-ma-why-is-my-crystalreportviewer-not.html